# Linear transformation from unit cube to unit cube

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Well, I have a unit cube in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with vertices at $(0, 0, 0)$, $(1, 0, 0)$, $(0, 1, 0)$, $(1, 1, 0)$, $(0, 0, 1)$, $(1, 0, 1)$, $(0, 1, 0)$, $(1, 1, 1)$.
I am trying to find all matrices which transform this unit cube to exactly another unit cube in $\mathbb{R}^3$. How can I describe them?
I think that it is rotations, symmetries, shifts. What have I forgotten?

Comment: Linear shifts are somewhat scarce.

Comment: Indeed, translations are affine transformations.Linear transformations must map 0 to 0.

Comment: Thank you, without shifts. Only rotations and symmetry?